# .css and .animate not executing sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

In below code , I am trying to hide div and then animate width .

my problem is  animate occurs first and later display none is getting applied .how can i make sure that they are executed in sequence .

```
$('.manufacture-details').css('display', 'none');
            $('.dropdown-section').animate({
                'width' : 320
            }, 200);
```

Comment: are you trying to do this on click ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying but it's working ok, just look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h20kLf91/) , I removed the 'none' so you can see the animation occur, after that, add none back where it belongs and click Run and you will see it's working, the dislay:none; takes place before the animation.

HTML

```
<div class="manufacture-details">
    <div class="dropdown-section"></div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.manufacture-details').css('display', '');
$('.dropdown-section').animate({
    'width': 320
}, 200);
```

CSS

```
.manufacture-details {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:red;
}
.dropdown-section {
    height:200px;
    width:100px;
    background:blue;
}
```

So I'm guessing your problem is someplace else...need more code to figure out what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply removing .css() to .hide() , as .hide() provides callback function .

```
         //hide manufacture div
        $('.manufacture-details').hide( "fast", function() {
            //Animation complete.
            $('.dropdown-section').animate({
                'width' : 320
            }, 200,function(){
                sliding_status=false;
            });
          });
```